# How to include C++ headers with a library name using CMakeLists.txt?

Tags: cmake

I have C++ source code in following hierarchy

```
main.cxx
CMakeLists.txt
someDirectory/myClass.cxx
someDirectory/myClass.h
```

My CMakeLists.txt is as follows

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(cmakePjt)
include_directories(someDirectory)
add_executable(cmakePjt main.cxx)
```

My main.cxx includes myClass as follows

```
#include "myClass.h"
```

And the above works! But I want to include myClass in my main.cxx as follows and how should I change my CMakeLists.txt for that?

```
 #include "myLibName/myClass.h"
```

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing CMakeLists can do. You have to actually create an existing actual directory with the name `myLibName`, move the .h file to that directory, and add the containing directory of that directory to include the search path.

Your project may look for example like this:

```
main.cxx
CMakeLists.txt
myLibName/src/myClass.cxx
myLibName/include/myLibName/myClass.h
myLibName/CMakeLists.txt
```

Where:

```
# myLibName/CMakeLists.txt
add_library(myLibName src/myClass.cxx)
target_include_directories(myLibName PUBLIC ./include)

# CMakeLists.txt
add_subdirectory(myLibName)
add_executable(cmakePjt mina.cxx)
target_link_libraries(cmakePjt PRIVATE myLibName)
```

Comment: Technically you could create logic in the `CMakeLists.txt` that copies the headers to the appropriate directory structure. This would be a terrible idea, but it would be possible. (Upvoted nonetheless.)